# Slow code; search for keyword in column, then change value of entire cell accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset, data-analysis

I've been trying to learn Python Data Analytics by working on a little dataset of job postings.

The dataset table consists of three columns; job title, country, and job description.

Some of the cells in the **job title** column contains values like:

- "Urgently Data Analyst needed - one year contract"
- "Junior Data Analyst required, big hearts preferred"
- "Senior Data Analytics position, two openings, ability to swim is a plus"

which I wanted to change to something simple, that can be aggregated like:
*"Data Analyst"*

After a lot of searching and browsing through the numpy and pandas documentation I couldn't find any function with the sole purpose of doing this, all of the functions I found does something along the lines of replacing the **found** expressions with a new one, so I figure I'd have to use if statements anyways, so I did the code as shown in the next section. But I feel like it is too slow and long, there must be a better way to do this right?

***TLDR; Code slow and long because I use too many ifs and don't know what else to do.***

This is the code:

Imports (I'm using google jupyter notebook)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Reading csv and dropping some columns (total rows ~40k)

```
jobscsv = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/allJobs.csv")

jobscsv.head

jobscsv_modified = jobscsv.drop(['Date-Posted', 'Salary', 'Company', 'Job-Type'], axis=1)

jobscsv_modified.head
```

This is the problematic part

```
success_counter = 0

for i in range(0, len(jobscsv_modified)):

    if "Data Analyst" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Analyst'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Data Analysis" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Analyst'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Data Analytics" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Analyst'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1
##
    if "Data Scientist" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Scientist'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Data Science" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Scientist'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Data Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Scientist'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Data Architect" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Scientist'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Machine Learning" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Scientist'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if " AI " in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Scientist'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Artificial Intelligence" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Scientist'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Database" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Database Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Data Entry" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Data Entry'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1
##
    if "Customer Service" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Customer Service'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Sales" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Sales'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1
##
    if "Software" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Programmer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Web Development" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Programmer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Stack" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Programmer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1
##
    if "Volunteer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Volunteer Work'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Laboratory" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Research'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Research" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Research'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "PhD" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'PhD'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Teacher" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Education'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Lecturer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Education'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Principal" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Education'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Dean" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Education'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "School" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Education'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Student" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Education'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Instructor" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Education'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Postdoctoral" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Research'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

##

    if "Mechanical Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Mechanical Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Industrial Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Industrial Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Mechatronics Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Mechatronics Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Electrical Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Electrical Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Civil Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Civil Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Chemical Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Chemical Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Process Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Process Engineer'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1

    if "Lab Engineer" in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
      jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = 'Research'
      success_counter = success_counter + 1
```

I've reached the point where I'm fairly confident no one does this. How can I improve it?

Comment: You should put all that code in a function that returns the updated job title. Then you can do `jobcsv['Job-Title'] = jobcsv['Job-Title'].apply(yourFunction)`

Comment: I know you are aware that this is the wrong way to solve this problem, but I'll note that you should have `elif`s for all but the first one. I believe that will actually speed up the code a little bit since it won't always have to check every single `if`.

Comment: I'll make sure to remember both tips; thank you both for the informative input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Based on your comment, it sounds like speed is important. I have a new solution that is both faster and cleaner. As before, I assume you don't need the success counts.

Still using a dictionary containing the keyword and what to replace with, we can instead use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). This is a vectorized function (so it will be fast) that checks if a condition is met. Where it is met, it will do nothing, but where it fails, it will update the value with what you specify. To do the check, we will use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to search for the keywords in the desired column. Since `where` only updates if `False`, we will add `~` beforehand, which is the logical NOT.

To use this, we will simply loop through the dictionary of replacements and check each key, updating the data frame where the condition is met.

```py
for key, value in replacements.items():
    df["Job-Title"].where(~df["Job-Title"].str.contains(key), value, inplace=True)
```

I've run some tests:

| Rows | Original | Updated | Richard |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1400 | 70.2ms | 36.1ms | 112ms |
| 14,000 | 667ms | 208ms | 1.133s |
| 250,000 | 11.30s | 3.153s | 20.05s |

Clearly, my updated version is the fastest and my previous version comes in second.

### Original Answer

Assuming you don't actually need to keep track of the successes, you can use the [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method. For the `replace` method, you can pass a dictionary of replacements, where keys are what to look for and values are what to replace it with. Because you want to replace the entire string if it contains the key words, we can use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

The regex we will use here is `(^.*<word>.*$)`.

- `(...)`: This makes everything one group.
- `^`: This matches the beginning of the word.
- `.*`: The `.` means "match any character" and `*` means "match zero or more of what's before it". Together it means it will match zero or more of any character.
- `<word>`: This is where you'd put the word you want the regex to search for, i.e. "PhD" or "Machine Learning".
- `$`: This matches the end of the word.

Since it will be annoying to write the regex around every single replacement, we will write a function to convert the replacements into regex form.

```py
regexify = lambda d: {f"(^.*{key}.*$)":value for key, value in d.items()}
```

Now, here's what you'll do.

1. Create a dictionary of replacements and what to replace them with, e.g. `{"Data Analyst":"Data Analyst", "Data Analysis":"Data Analyst", ..., "Software":"Programmer",...}`.
2. "Regexify" it by passing the dictionary to the function.
3. Call the `replace` method with `regex=True`. You can also choose to use `inplace=True`.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

# I put some random characters before and after the word to simulate your data
old = ["salkd old 1 asfgds", "asdfa old 2 ffdz", "afsfd old 3 asfds"] 

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":random.choices(old, k=12)})
print(df)

replacements = {"old 1":"new 1", "old 2":"new 2", "old 3":"new 3"}
regexify = lambda d: {f"(^.*{key}.*$)":value for key, value in d.items()}
replacements_regexed = regexify(replacements)

df["A"] = df["A"].replace(replacements_regexed, regex=True)
# df["A"].replace(replacements_regexed, regex=True, inplace=True)  # same result
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
# Before replacement
                     A
0     asdfa old 2 ffdz
1   salkd old 1 asfgds
2     asdfa old 2 ffdz
3    afsfd old 3 asfds
4     asdfa old 2 ffdz
5    afsfd old 3 asfds
6     asdfa old 2 ffdz
7     asdfa old 2 ffdz
8     asdfa old 2 ffdz
9   salkd old 1 asfgds
10    asdfa old 2 ffdz
11   afsfd old 3 asfds

# After replacement
        A
0   new 2
1   new 1
2   new 2
3   new 3
4   new 2
5   new 3
6   new 2
7   new 2
8   new 2
9   new 1
10  new 2
11  new 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did look into regex and replace but could have never figured this solution out on my own.
A sophisticated solution; this is much more organized and efficient. Thanks.

Comment: P.S: For some reason it takes significantly more time than regular looping + dictionary in the other answer. I'm happy anyway; just thought it could be beneficial to share that information here.

Comment: @HeshamMOmar Are you sure? I ran some tests and my version was faster. I've also updated my answer for an even faster option and I included my speed tests.

Comment: If you ran the tests then I'm definitely not sure lol. This is precisely the reason I shared this remark with you. Now I know maybe something else I'm doing is wrong, or maybe something in the environment.
Thank you for the updated version, I'll make sure to try it... my next dataset has ~2 mil. rows lol.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to reduce all those `if`s and then `break` at the first match.

```py
title_map = {
    'Data Analyst': 'Analyst', 'Data Analysis': 'Analyst', 'Data Analytics': 'Analyst',
    'Data Scientist': 'Scientist', 'Data Science': 'Scientist', 'Data Engineer': 'Scientist',
    'Data Architect': 'Scientist', 'Machine Learning': 'Scientist', 'AI': 'Scientist',
    'Artificial Intelligence': 'Scientist', 'Database': 'Engineer', 'Data Entry': 'Entry',
    'Customer Service': 'Service', 'Sales': 'Sales', 'Software': 'Programmer',
    'Web Development': 'Programmer', 'Stack': 'Programmer', 'Volunteer': 'Work',
    'Laboratory': 'Research', 'Research': 'Research', 'PhD': 'PhD', 'Teacher': 'Education',
    'Lecturer': 'Education', 'Principal': 'Education', 'Dean': 'Education',
    'School': 'Education', 'Student': 'Education', 'Instructor': 'Education',
    'Postdoctoral': 'Research', 'Mechanical Engineer': 'Engineer',
    'Industrial Engineer': 'Engineer', 'Mechatronics Engineer': 'Engineer',
    'Electrical Engineer': 'Engineer', 'Civil Engineer': 'Engineer',
    'Chemical Engineer': 'Engineer', 'Process Engineer': 'Engineer',
    'Lab Engineer': 'Research'}

success_counter = 0

for i in range(0, len(jobscsv_modified)):
    
    for key in title_map:
        if key in jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i]:
            jobscsv_modified['Job-Title'][i] = title_map[key]
            success_counter += 1
            break
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this is much more organized and efficient.